# How to get a whole number value from a variable in php?

Tags: php

The following is my code,

```
    $da =01;
    $cal_sunday = $da + 7;
    echo $cal_sunday;
```

the above calculation return the output as '8'.. i need the output as '08'...

Comment: When you assigned 01 to $da, you were assigning a value of 1 (the leading zero was irrelevant and ignored by PHP5). So when you added 7 and echoed the result, the value of 8 was completely correct. It *was the whole number*. To output '08' implies you wanted a string, which of course the answers provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) to format your number:

```
echo sprintf('%02u', $cal_sunday);
```

Comment: echo sprintf() is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write echo sprintf() in any code for any reason -- it should be printf() every time.

Answer (score 1):

you can use printf eg `printf("%02d",$cal_sunday);`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function

Your calculation produces and integer but you require a string.

Use sprintf to return the string in the format you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$da = 1;
$cal_sunday = $da + 7;
printf('%02s', $cal_sunday);
```

`printf()` and `sprintf()` work similarly, except the first does a direct output, while the later returns the value so it can be assigned to another variable.

```
$da = 1;
$cal_sunday = sprintf('%02s', $da + 7);
echo $cal_sunday;
```